# How to export ditaa or dot blocks as captioned figures (LaTeX)?

Tags: emacs, export, latex, org-mode

I have an org-mode document with captioned ditaa and dot figures.  When I export to LaTeX, the resulting images are not placed inside a `figure` environment, not given a `\caption`, and not given a `\label`.  Other source code blocks export fine.

How can I fix this?

Here is an example org-mode document:

```
* Plain source code works

#+CAPTION: This works
#+LABEL: fig:works
#+BEGIN_SRC
this is a test
#+END_SRC

The above (Figure [[fig:works]]) is a figure with some source code.  When
exported to LaTeX, it is placed inside a ~figure~ environment and
given a caption and label as expected.

* Ditaa doesn't work

#+CAPTION: Foo
#+LABEL: fig:foo
#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file foo.png :cmdline -E
                              /-----\
----------------------------->| foo |<-----------------------------
                              \-----/
#+END_SRC

The above (Figure [[fig:foo]]) is a ditaa figure.  When exported to LaTeX,
the image is not inside a ~figure~ environment, it is missing the
caption, and there is no ~\label~.

* Dot doesn't work

#+CAPTION: Bar
#+LABEL: fig:bar
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file bar.png
digraph foo {
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf -> b;
}
#+END_SRC

The above (Figure [[fig:bar]]) is a dot figure.  When exported to LaTeX,
the image is not inside a ~figure~ environment, it is missing the
caption, and there is no ~\label~.

#+OPTIONS: toc:nil author:nil
#+TITLE:
#+DATE:
```

I'm using org-mode 8.2.10 on Emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it to work you need to have a `#+RESULTS:` section under the `#+BEGIN_SRC` block and caption that instead:

```
* Plain source code

#+CAPTION: This works
#+LABEL: fig:works
#+BEGIN_SRC
this is a test
#+END_SRC

See Figure [[fig:works]].

* Ditaa

#+BEGIN_SRC ditaa :file foo.png :cmdline -E
                              /-----\
----------------------------->| foo |<-----------------------------
                              \-----/
#+END_SRC

#+CAPTION: Foo
#+LABEL: fig:foo
#+RESULTS:
[[file:foo.png]]

See Figure [[fig:foo]].

* Dot

#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file bar.png
digraph foo {
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf -> b;
}
#+END_SRC

#+CAPTION: Bar
#+LABEL: fig:bar
#+RESULTS:
[[file:bar.png]]

See Figure [[fig:bar]].

#+OPTIONS: toc:nil author:nil
#+TITLE:
#+DATE:
```

Comment: This does work for LaTeX output, although unfortunately it doesn't also work for HTML output.  Also note that if you do `C-c C-c` evaluation, it will clobber any existing `#+RESULTS` block, along with any `#+CAPTION` and `#+LABEL` you've added before it.

Comment: HTML output seems to be fixed as of writing this comment